# Which is better for core strength: cycling or running?

Tags: bicycling, jogging, core

The question title is fairly self-explanatory. I used to be moderately fit because I cycled to the office, but two years of home working has seen my fitness levels plummet. I recently injured my back quite badly doing nothing of any particular note and the doctor said it was likely due to my low fitness levels, and that I needed to start exercising again to work my core.

I'm aware there are a lot of low-impact exercises I can do that target the core, but I figured it was about time I started some aerobic exercise, too. So: which is likely to be best for my all-around and core fitness: cycling or jogging?

Comment: Depends; biking is easier on the body, though. It's easy enough to search for the differences and see which suits *you specifically*. For *core* fitness you should do core exercises; both running and cycling work the core to a degree, but it's neither's primary benefit. I don't see why you can't do both.

Comment: @DaveNewton - The OP may be time limited, or have other reasons for wanting to one or the other. You state they both work the core to a degree, maybe outlining the differences would make for a good answer?

Comment: Straight up running. The repetitive raising of the leg is like reverse crunches. I do not regard running and jogging the same. For most of us, (myself included) getting up from our chairs more regularly will help. Try both and see which you enjoy, that's what's really important.